# magento, 2 stores and one corporate section

Tags: magento-1.8

What is the best way to set up three different stores in magento with different domainnames and one corporate section with a landingpage, customer service, about us, etc?

Something like this:

www.domainname.nl  (corporate)

www.domainname-store1.nl (store 1)

www.domainname-store2.nl (store 2)

www.domainname-store3.nl (store 3)

I can set-up 4 store views in the store management. But how can I link to cms pages in de corporate section, from the store sections?

Answer (score 0):

I have on one magento system multi-domains.

- www.example.com (**website scope  1**)
- www.example2.com (**website scope 2**)

And In magentoROOT/**index.php**: add these lines:

```
   /* Run store or run website */
    $mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

    // Add This 
 switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
        case 'www.exmample.com':

            $mageRunCode = 'base';
            $mageRunType = 'website';
        break;

        case 'www.example2.com':

            $mageRunCode = 'websitecode2';
            $mageRunType = 'website';
        break;


    }

    // Add This
    Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Then need configurate System > Configuration > General > Web > Actual urls.
That is it! :)

About Landing Pages...
For one customer service, about us, type one page, etc..  deligate permisions for each scope.
For Example:

**About Us**
(scope 1, scope 2)

Same on example.com and example2.com

If there need some changes in **About Us** content, then you need seperate about us page for each scope.

Comment: What do you mean by "delegate permission for each scope"? For example: i have some links in my footer links. One of them is about us. But, because i have set the scope from about us to the www.domainname.nl, it is not clickable.

Comment: Delegate: Select all Store View scopes, where about us need to shows!

Comment: hmm, i don't think you understand me. :-) If i delegate for every store; the links to the "about us" page will be:

www.domainname.nl/aboutus
or: www.domainname-store1.nl/aboutus
ór: www.domainname-store2.nl/aboutus
ór: www.domainname-store3.nl/aboutus

Depending on the store, where i'm clicking on the link. 

If i'm in store1, I want to go to www.domainname.nl/aboutus instead of  www.domainname-store1.nl/aboutus

Comment: Well, i think You in url need set relative cms address (about) , not full with (www.example.com/about)